# How to access item 2 (or 3 or ...x) of an IEnumerable Model by ID

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am looking for a best practice.  I have something that works, but I don't know if it's "right."

I am building a page where a customer can enter payment data for three different types of permits. I am sending an IEnumerable of my permit.  It contains 3 null permits.

Clarification: An end user can have either 1, 2, or 3 permits, and each permit is of a unique type -- either "fishing," "boating," or "concessions."

I have built the view around this concept:

```
<div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-md-2" align="right" style="padding-top:5px">
                <strong>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().Notes, "Notes:", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })</strong>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4" align="left">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Take(1).FirstOrDefault().Notes, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Take(1).FirstOrDefault().PermitTypeId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4" align="left">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Skip(1).Take(1).FirstOrDefault().Notes, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Skip(1).Take(1).FirstOrDefault().PermitTypeId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4" align="left">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Skip(2).Take(1).FirstOrDefault().Notes, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Skip(2).Take(1).FirstOrDefault().PermitTypeId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The customer enters the data for each appropriate payment type, the Save button sends the data back, and I check to see if each payment type is not null, then process as usual.

Is this the right way to do this? Is there a better way?

Any input would be appreciated.

Regards,
Carthax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `foreach` loop in your markup to loop through the enumerable.

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-2" align="right" style="padding-top:5px">
        <strong>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().Notes, "Notes:", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="row">
            foreach (var item in Model)  
            {  
                <div class="col-md-4" align="left">
                    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Notes, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => item.PermitTypeId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oooh.. Oh, duh.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

IEnumerable cannot be accessed directly by index. The more readable cycle statement that you can use is a foreach, then check for the ID using an if statement.

As the worst complexity of this search is O(n) as it must cycle against every item, the forach solution is ok for me.

I don't know exactly your code base or model, but if you fail validation just if only one of the IDs is null the following code will be my best catch:

```
private bool ValidateCollection(IEnumerable<Item> itemsCollction)
{
    foreach(Item item in itemsCollction)
    {
       if(item.ID == null)
          return false;    // At least one of the elements have ID null.
    }
    return true;
}
```

Just to say:
LINQ can also be used, but on average cases the execution is far slower than a foreach, because LINQ query creates a lot of overhead.

You can convert the enumerable to an array or list using constructors, but still it must cycle over every item in the collection. Then you can use a for to cycle the array that performs far better than foreach, but this can be useful only if you will reuse the result of the first conversion often. If not, you've wasted time convert IEnumerable to a List or Array.